# Issue with PathGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, version-8

**Bug introduced in 8.0.0 and fixed in 9.0.0**

---

I am having a strange issue with `PathGraph`. Executing

```
PathGraph[{a, b, c}]
```

or `PathGraph[{1,2,3}]`, etc., returns a path-graph with three vertices as expected. However, executing:

```
In[10]:= PathGraph[{v1, v2, v3}]
Out[10]= PathGraph[{v1, v2, v3}]
```

That is, it stays unevaluated instead of returning the `Graph` object. I tried several variations and apparently the issue occurs whenever `v2` is among the vertices. That is all of `PathGraph[{a1, v2, a3}]`, `PathGraph[{v2, x}]`, `PathGraph[{1, 2, v2, x}]`, etc. remain unevaluated after execution.

I tried this on two computers, both with clean Kernels (with no definitions made or packages loaded, etc.).

Mathematica version: 8.0.0.0

Can anyone reproduce this? Is this a bug?

Comment: I can repro this one. Awful.

Comment: Me too.  Also, neither of these work either: PathGraph[{j, k, l}]; 
PathGraph[{v, w, x}]

Comment: Daniel Lichtblau has, on several occasions, commented/answered saying that such bugs are often caused by some internal variable sorting or issues with hashing. There is no way to predict which ones will fail, but they fix them as they find them. Here's [a rather nasty bug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5402214)  on versions 7 and below (fixed in 8 onwards) that's somewhat related. I'd suggest emailing to support@wolfram.com

Comment: I emailed them. Waiting for reply.

Comment: @becko Please share the reply when you get one.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sure. See the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. I emailed Wolfram support and got the following reply:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your email.
>
> I have reproduced this problem.  It seems that PathGraph doesn't like
>   variable names like v2, x, and l, but generally works for other
>   variable names. I have filed a report with our developers on this
>   issue.  Your contact information has been added to the report so that
>   you can be notified when this problem is resolved.
>
> If I hear any intermediate feedback from the developers, I will be
>   sure to pass it on to you.  Right now, but guess is that there is some
>   sort of collision between the variable names and some internal
>   variable that is causing the problem.  Therefore, the only real
>   solution (beyond just avoiding those variable names) is to change the
>   built in function definition.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Technical Support Wolfram Research, Inc.
>   http://support.wolfram.com

Comment: This is now fixed in version 9.  I'll include an edit in the question if you don't mind.